# Hover two different elements

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I have two elements that hover when you mouse over them independently, but I also want that when hovering the second element ("btn"), the first one ("i") also gets selected and hovers. There is more than one div, so it should work the same way in every div.

I have tried first with CSS using adjacent sibling selectors and then with the following jQuery statement (with some variations, but no result).

```
<div>
 <p class="i">Ilumínate</p>
 <h3>Web Development</h3>
 <p>Professional custom e-commerce and web design...</p>
 <a href="#" class="btn">Read more</a></div>
```

**CSS**

```
i{
  font-size: 60px;
    margin-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.8s;
    transition: color 0.8s;  
}   

i:hover{
  color: #1AC4F8
}

#services [class*="flaticon"]:hover{
    color: #1AC4F8
}

.btn{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: 2px solid #1AC4F8;
    color: #1AC4F8;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.8s, background-color 0.8s;
    transition: color 0.8s, background-color 0.8s
}

.btn:hover{
    background-color: #1AC4F8;
    color: #F2F2F2;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('#btn').hover(function(){
$(this).prev('.i').css( "color", "#1AC4F8" ) });
```

[Here's a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zkyu3kvd/2/)

Comment: this isn't a code writing service. You should show what you have tried to solve this problem

Comment: @charlietfl Well OP has added a fiddle too

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri that fiddle doesn't show any attempt to solve issue and doesn't show anything different than in what is already in the question

Comment: @charlietfl  yeah right

Comment: Thank you @ShubhamKhatri for your assistance. charlietfl of course, I only wanted to simplify the issue and don't mislead anyone. I'm going to show what I've tried besides updating the question because it is a bit more complex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of `prevAll` with a required class because `prev()` just gives the prev sibling

```js
$('.btn').on('mouseenter', function(){
   
 $(this).prevAll('.i:first').addClass('hovering');
})
$('.btn').on('mouseleave', function(){

 $(this).prevAll('.i:first').removeClass('hovering');
})
```

```css
.i{
  font-size: 20px;
 margin-left: 0;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.8s;
 transition: color 0.8s;  
} 

.i:hover, .hovering{
  color: #1AC4F8
}


#services [class*="flaticon"]:hover{
 color: #1AC4F8
}

.btn{
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 border: 2px solid #1AC4F8;
 color: #1AC4F8;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.8s, background-color 0.8s;
 transition: color 0.8s, background-color 0.8s
}

.btn:hover{
 background-color: #1AC4F8;
 color: #F2F2F2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
     <p class="i">Ilumínate 1</p>
     <h3>Web Development</h3>
     <p>Professional custom e-commerce and web design to let your business grow at a rapid pace. See how we do that.</p>
     <a href="#" class="btn">Read more</a>
</div>

<div>
     <p class="i">Ilumínate 2</p>
     <h3>Web Development</h3>
     <p>Professional custom e-commerce and web design to let your business grow at a rapid pace. See how we do that.</p>
     <a href="#" class="btn">Read more</a>
</div>
```

Comment: not going to be instance specific if there are more than one of each in page

Comment: yes, that's right @charlietfl I tried to put it simple but it has been a mistake. There are going to be several divs like this one in page

Comment: Okay, I understand  the requirement now better

Comment: @Alvarado87  could you see the updated code and tell if it fits your requirement

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```js
$( ".btn" ).mouseover(function() {
   $(this).siblings( ".i" ).toggleClass( "hover" );
});
$( ".btn" ).mouseleave(function() {
   $(this).siblings( ".i" ).toggleClass( "hover" );
});
```

```css
.i{
  font-size: 20px;
 margin-left: 0;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.8s;
 transition: color 0.8s;  
} 

.i:hover{
  color: #1AC4F8
}

#services [class*="flaticon"]:hover{
 color: #1AC4F8
}

.btn{
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 border: 2px solid #1AC4F8;
 color: #1AC4F8;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.8s, background-color 0.8s;
 transition: color 0.8s, background-color 0.8s
}

.btn:hover,
.hover {
 background-color: #1AC4F8;
 color: #F2F2F2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
     <p class="i">Ilumínate</p>
     <h3>Web Development</h3>
     <p>Professional custom e-commerce and web design to let your business grow at a rapid pace. See how we do that.</p>
     <a href="#" class="btn">Read more</a>
</div>
<div>
     <p class="i">Ilumínate</p>
     <h3>Web Development</h3>
     <p>Professional custom e-commerce and web design to let your business grow at a rapid pace. See how we do that.</p>
     <a href="#" class="btn">Read more</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but there are going to be more divs in the same page. I should have said it in the first place

Comment: I adjusted my code so now you can target diverent divs